# Php uploading images to a server

Tags: php, image, forms, oop, get

I'm having a bit of a problem trying to upload an image to a server.
These are the errors I'm getting:

> Notice: Undefined index: $this->file in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/php/theislan_testdatabase/addItem.php on line 70
>
> Notice: Undefined index: $this->file in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/php/theislan_testdatabase/addItem.php on line 71
>
> Notice: Undefined index: $this->file in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/php/theislan_testdatabase/addItem.php on line 72

I thing the problem is in the constructor of this class.

```
public function __construct() {

        $this->submit  = isset($_GET['submit'])? 1 : 0;
        $this->errors = array();
        //$this->product_id = $this->filter($_GET['product_id']);
        $this->name = $this->filter($_GET['name']);
        $this->description = $this->filter($_GET['description']);
        $this->cost = $this->filter($_GET['cost']);
        $this->numinstock = $this->filter($_GET['numinstock']);
        //$this->picture = $this->filter($_GET['picture']);
        $this->type = $this->filter($_GET['type']);
        $this->file = $_GET['file'];
        $this->token = $_GET['token'];
    }
```

This line to be precise: $this->file = $_GET['file'];

This is the part of that class that is giving me the errors

```
        public function addNew() {
       


   $databaseinst = database:: getinstance();
   $conn =   $databaseinst->connect();
   
   
   

   $query = "INSERT INTO  Product (name , description, cost, numinstock, type, image)  VALUES ('$this->name', '$this->description',  
   '$this->cost','$this->numinstock', '$this->type', 'images/$this->name')";
        //description = '$this->description' cost = '$this->cost' numinstock = '$this->numinstock' picture = '$this->picture' type = '$this->type'
   $result = $databaseinst->querydb($query);
   
   $id = mysql_insert_id();
   
   //upload file
   if ((($_FILES['$this->file']["type"] == "image/gif")
   ||($_FILES['$this->file']["type"] == "image/jpeg")
   ||($_FILES['$this->file']["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
   &&($_FILES['$this->file']["type"] < 40000000))
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["$this->file"]["tmp_name"],"images/" . $id.".jpq");
   
   

       if ( false===$result ) {

            $errorno =mysqli_errno($conn);

             if ($errorno === 1062)
             {
     $this->errors[]= "this user already exists on the database. please try signing!";
             }
             else
             {
             $this->errors[]= "error creating new user 
             name = '$this->name' description = '$this->description' cost = '$this->cost' numinstock = '$this->numinstock' 
     type = '$this->type'
             ";
             }
    }

        
        if($conn == null)
        {
        $this->errors[] = "difficulty is being experienced connecting to the server. Please try again in a moment!";
        }
       
    }
```

This is where I get the users input:

```
                    <li><b><cart><form method = "get" action="">
                                        <?php
                                        printf("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"MAX_FILE_SIZE\" value=\"4000000\" />");
      printf("<p>Name: <input type='text' name=\"name\" id=\"styled\";\"></p>");
      printf("<p>Type: <input type='text' name=\"type\" id=\"styled\";\"></p>");
      printf("<p>Picture: <input type=\"file\" name=\"file\" id=\"file\" \></p>");
      printf("<p>Cost: <input type='text' onkeypress='validate(event)' name=\"cost\" id=\"styled\";\"></input></p>");
      printf("<p>Number Instock: <input type='text' onkeypress='validate(event)' name=\"numinstock\" id=\"styled\";\"></p>");
                   printf("<p>Description: <textarea  rows=\"6\" cols=\"200\" name=\"description\" id=\"styled\";\"></textarea></p>");
                                        ?>
                                    <p><input type="submit" value="Add Item" name="submitAdd" />
                                        <input type="hidden"  name ="token" value="<?= $_SESSION['token']; ?>"
                                               /></p></form></cart></b></li>
```

Thanks.

Comment: which lines are 70,71 and 72?

Comment: Sorry they are: if ((($_FILES['$this->file']["type"] == "image/gif")
       ||($_FILES['$this->file']["type"] == "image/jpeg")
       ||($_FILES['$this->file']["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
       &&($_FILES['$this->file']["type"] < 40000000))

Comment: try changing the double quotes with single? => $_FILES['$this->file']['type']

Comment: if you remove that if check does it work?

Comment: No I get: Undefined index: bg_3_02.jpg in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/php/theislan_testdatabase/addItem.php on line 69
that line is: move_uploaded_file($_FILES["$this->file"]["tmp_name"],"images/" . $id.".jpq");

Comment: check out this article from the php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php - Have you tried reading them from an array?

Comment: 1. I don't think you can upload files using the 'get' method ... you need to post the data. 2. You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form definition tag ..

Answer (score 0):

Don't put quotes around `$this->file` when it is used as an index.